# DLL File in Toolbox in Visual Studio 2017 was deleted every time I changed the resolution

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I try to add .dll file in toolbox. I follow all the procedures and it work properly, the problem is that whenever I change the resolution of my computer the .dll file I added was gone. Please help me

Comment: Please specify your problem in more details. I can not understand what are you doing and what is the result. The DLL file got deleted when you change resolution? That would be the first time I heard of something like this. The imported DLL is no longer imported after resolution change? There are a few applications that have different visual settings for different resolution.

Comment: Sorry. Yes the dll file got deleted whenever i changed the resolution. I changed my resolution to 768 when i try to code then changed it to 1080 when watching movie or playing games. What should I do to make the DLL file stays even i change my resolution? I'm using visual studio 2017 community.

Comment: Please provide the exact steps that lead to this behavior. This is surprising, to say the least.

Comment: As first step, try to identify who deleted the file. Download [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), set filter to specific file and change resolution. And also, you can try to set the attributes to 'read only'. Standard delete should no longer work.